# Infilling every other Row in a Pandas Dataframe the the value from the last row + 30 minutes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I'm adding dummy rows to some data so I am able to Join it with an existing dataset. I need data every 30 minutes but the dataset has every 1 hour. I have created a dummy row for every other row and imputed its value using `.ffill()` but have no idea of to fill the Pandas time series in the same manner but add 30 minutes to each value.

I want something along this line that replaces `Nan` values and indexes 30 minutes from the last non-Nan.

Input DF

```
0        2011-11-11 00:00:00
1        Nan
2        2011-11-11 01:00:00
3        Nan
4        2011-11-11 02:00:00
```

Code

```
df['time'] = df['time'].ffill() + 000-00-00 00:30:00
```

Output

```
0        2011-11-11 00:00:00
1        2011-11-11 00:30:00
2        2011-11-11 01:00:00
3        2011-11-11 01:30:00
4        2011-11-11 02:00:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['time'] = df['time'].fillna(df['time'].shift() + pd.Timedelta('30 min'))
```

Alternatively, if you are **sure** that there are no missed rows, you can just generate the new timestamps:

```py
min_time = df.loc[0, 'time']
df['time'] = pd.date_range(min_time, freq='30 min', periods=len(df))
```